# Table not created in MySql DB after starting Spring Boot application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, model-view-controller, phpmyadmin

The project uses a database MySql, Open Server. Here is my application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:8888/citatnik_bd
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql: true
```

Here is my entity:

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="Quotes")
public class Quotes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long ID;

    private String ru, by, ua, en;

    public Long GetID() { return ID; }
    public void SetID(Long ID) { this.ID = ID; }

    public String GetBy() { return by; }
    public void SetBy(String by) { this.by = by; }

    public String GetRu() { return ru; }
    public void SetRu(String ru) { this.ru = ru; }

    public String GetUa() { return ua; }
    public void SetUa(String ua) { this.ua = ua; }

    public String GetEn() { return en; }
    public void SetEn(String en) { this.by = en; }
}
```

By the way, everything is fine in the pom.xml file, all the necessary dependencies are registered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.Citatnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>Citatnik</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Citatnik</name>
    <description>Citatnik project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Here is logging out from Spring application:

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)

2023-07-31T19:01:34.457+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] c.Citatnik.Citatnik.CitatnikApplication  : Starting CitatnikApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 3336 (C:\Users\dddry\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Цитатник\Citatnik\target\classes started by dddry in C:\Users\dddry\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Цитатник\Citatnik)
2023-07-31T19:01:34.461+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] c.Citatnik.Citatnik.CitatnikApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-07-31T19:01:34.539+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-07-31T19:01:34.539+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-07-31T19:01:35.213+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-07-31T19:01:35.232+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 11 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-07-31T19:01:35.866+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-31T19:01:35.876+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-31T19:01:35.876+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
2023-07-31T19:01:35.945+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-31T19:01:35.946+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1405 ms
2023-07-31T19:01:36.094+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-07-31T19:01:36.148+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
2023-07-31T19:01:36.149+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-07-31T19:01:36.272+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-31T19:01:36.396+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-07-31T19:01:36.409+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-07-31T19:01:36.664+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@41c02a96
2023-07-31T19:01:36.666+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-07-31T19:01:36.824+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
2023-07-31T19:01:37.044+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-07-31T19:01:37.048+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-07-31T19:01:37.094+03:00  WARN 3336 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-07-31T19:01:37.542+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-07-31T19:01:37.574+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-31T19:01:37.585+03:00  INFO 3336 --- [  restartedMain] c.Citatnik.Citatnik.CitatnikApplication  : Started CitatnikApplication in 3.679 seconds (process running for 4.084)
```

I checked the port, database name, username and password - everything is correct. However, when I run the application and go to phpMyAdmin, I see a message that no tables were found in the database. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Welcome at stackoverflow. Please add logging output from the spring application.

Comment: But you haven't shown any code *doing* anything with your entity...

Comment: So far, there is no code that does anything with the entity...

Comment: Your configuration looks good. But I wonder about the logging output! The line `HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl` is the 100% proof that your connection established successfully. *But* Since hibernate is a direct dependency of data-jpa (as you can see here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/3.1.2 ) I miss the log what dialect is used! I think it is a dependency problem. Please post all dependencies used in the `pom.xml`.

Comment: I'd try to create and save an entity

Comment: @Grim, I have added full pom.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using spring-boot 3.1.2, it mean you should replace your

```
import javax.persistence.*;
```

with

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
```

About your maven dependency you should to remove this one

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

because you use

```
spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
```

it has dependencies on Hibernate. Hibernate then has a dependency on the jakarta.persistence API which makes its classes available to your application's code.

About your problem, you don't see the tables after application start.
Just try to replace an application properties param

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

And after first run of application

replace with `update`